# Vue vue-slider-component error, cannot be divisible by "interval"

Tags: vue.js

not too sure what this error means, i'm not too mathematical. This is the full error:

> [VueSlider error]: The prop "interval" is invalid, "(max - min)" cannot be divisible by "interval"

Here are my values:

```
const min = 500;
const max = 20000;
const interval = 200;

// const interval = 500; // This works fine
```

Can someone explain how I workout this calculation, mainly so I can add a check to display a message to a user, as these values can be customized with my settings.

Comment: just a guess, but sounds like (max - min) % interval needs to be 0,
or in other words, by adding interval n times to min, your max must be reachable

Comment: That makes sense, I wasn't sure on the calculation you see, can you put that as an answer as that does appear to be the case, thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

guess (max - min) % interval needs to be 0,

or in other words, by adding the interval n times to the min, your max must be reachable